# Bracket Question in Python . Solve in Minimum Time and Space?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I am trying to solve
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/bracket-sequence-1-40eab940/submissions/ in python

Its showing Time Exceed Error. Can anyone tell me how time complexity can be decreased?
Here is my code:

```
def findBalanced(expr):

    stack = []
    for char in expr:
        if char in ['(']:
            stack.append(char)
        else:
            if not stack:
                return False
            current_char = stack.pop()
            if current_char == '(':
                if char != ')':
                    return False
           

    if stack:
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = input()
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(expr)):
        expr = expr[1:] + expr[0]
        if findBalanced(expr):
            count +=1
        else:
            pass
    print(count)
```

How to solve this problem using minimum time and minimum space?

Comment: Can you tell us what problem exactly you're trying to solve? Here, not elsewhere?

Comment: I did not click the link, but the link contains "bracket-sequence" and the code defines a function "findBalanced" which returns a boolean, so I am guessing the goal is to take a string of `(` and `)` and decide whether it is a correctly parenthesised expression or not; e.g., `(()())()` is correct but `(()` is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Stef , No , its not the correct question. Please visit the link as stated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding the line `print(stack)` at the beginning or the `for` loop. Then execute your algorithm on a few example inputs. You might notice something a bit weird.

Please take a second to actually do it, and try to find out what's so weird about it. This will give you inspiration on how to improve your algorithm.

...

Did you do it? Please don't read further until you've done it.

The remainder of this answer assumes that you have added `print(stack)` at the beginning of the for loop, and that you have looked at the output on a few examples of input, and that you have tried to notice something a bit surprising about the outputs. Please do that before you read the remainder of this answer.

Your algorithm maintains a **stack**, but if you output the stack at every iteration, you'll notice something: the stack only contains copies of the character `(`. Nothing else. This is because the only occurrence of `stack.append(char)` is right under `if char in ['(']:`, so you are only ever appending `(`.

So really the only information contained in this stack is how many `(` it contains. Instead of actually maintaining the stack, you could simply maintain a counter, *i.e.*, an integer telling you how many `(` would be on the stack if you had a stack.

Replace `stack = []` with `depth = 0`, then `stack.append(char)` with `depth += 1` and `stack.pop()` with `depth -= 1`.

Your check `if current_char == '(':` is not useful at all, because the chars on the stack are all `(`, so the check is always true and thus redundant.

I will let you figure out on which values of the counter you should return true and on which values you should return false. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to improve my code by the suggestion which you have given. Meanwhile I have seen the best solution on HackerEarth :

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(s):
    p=0
    t=0
    res = 0
    for i in s:
        if(i=='('):
           
            p+=1
           
        else:
          
            p -= 1
          
        if (p<t):
            print(f"Values of p and t are {p} and {t}")
            t=p
            res = 0
        if(t==p):

            res+=1
            
    if p:
        return 0
    else:
        return res
s= input()
print(solve(s))
```

Comment: @Stef Could you please explain a bit

Comment: Hi! As it turns out, writing "@Stef" has no effect in StackOverflow, if Stef didn't previously comment on that post. So, I didn't receive a notification and I only just now saw your comment.